# create an html table from MS access DB with asp or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have an html table (3 cells per row) with each cell containing headshots (img) and then name, hometown, and class fields.

each headshot and name, hometown, and class relates to a member in a members table in an MS access DB.  I want to write either asp or jquery script to go through each table record (member) and display their picture, name, hometown, and class.

This is a rough conceptual asp version of what I want to create :
I would like to do this preferably in jquery... any help would be appreciated!  thanks

```
<%
    Dim Sql = "select * from Sheet1"


DR = DataReader  (SQL)
While Not DR.EOF
    x = 1
    If  x < 4 Then %>
        <td><img src="avatar-blank.jpg" alt="headshot"/><br /><p>dr("Name") <br />Hometown: VarAddress <br /> Class: VarClass</p></td>
   <%  Else
       x = 0  %>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="avatar-blank.jpg" alt="headshot" /><br /><p>VarName<br />Hometown: VarAddress<br />Class: VarClass</p></td>
   <%  End If
    x = x + 1
    DR.moveNext
Wend %>
```

I have this currently set up, its an html table inside a jquery-ui tabs.
I want to make all this images and other fields filled with the information from a corresponding MS access DB
[Link to Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/69372972@N06/6306591143/)

Comment: jQuery is a client side scripting tool and is probably not relevant to this problem since you are writing a server side script in what looks like ASP classic. Anyway. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @JohnFx
I want to dynamically create an html table with each cells contents being filled with an image and 2 text fields from an Access DB.  I would be ok with doing this in either asp or jquery (using JSON or ajax)  does that help?

Comment: @RickLiddle I am working in .net 4

Comment: @mumis2012 Your code example is in "Classic" ASP and is not appropriate for .NET 4 and your question about using jQuery demonstrates you are not familiar with the technology you are trying to use. Your question cannot be answered on this forum, you need to spend some time learning your technology, then come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is client-side and would require web services, there are plenty of examples, if you search [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery%20asp.net%20web%20services) or on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20asp.net%20web%20services&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Here is an example using an `asp:gridview` and `MS Access`:

[ind GridView with MS Access Database table in Asp.net](http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2009/11/bind-gridview-with-ms-access-database.html)